# Can't return element index in an array Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-3.x, indexing

I want to use the array.index(x) function multiple times to find the element index in a small list and its place within a larger list. For example, I have...

```
a=1
b=2
c=1
d=2

small_list = [a, b, c]
full_list = [d, c, b, a]

x=small_list.index(c)
y=full_list.index(x)
z=full_list[y]
```

When running, I get...

```
x=0
y=0
z=2
```

But I want to get...

```
x=2
y=1
z=1
```

How do I change my code to do this?
I can see that it is looking up the value of *c* when I run the code. How do I stop this happening?

EDIT: My own answer to my problem is below.

Comment: _"When running, I get..."_ You do? I get `ValueError: 0 is not in list`. Is this your actual code?

Comment: I'm not sure how your example input is meant to lead to your example output. Certainly the first index of 1 in your `small_list` is not 2.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a `list`, not an `array`. The `list.index()` method returns the `index` of the first value specified. So, when you ask for

```
small_list.index(c)
```

You're getting the `index` of `c`, which are the values 0 and 1, respectively.

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists

Answer (score 0):

I t looks like it is returning the correct value!  Your list [a,b,c] is [1,2,1].  So the index(c) (or index(1)) is returning the first instance of c, which is spot 0.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, I've found what I need to do:
Lists aren't the right basis for what I want to do, I think I should use tuples.
That way, if I define...

```
tuple1 = (a, b, c)
tuple2 = (d, c, b, a)

print(tuple1[c]) # =2
print(tuple2[c]) # =1
```

Which is what I want. Essentially, I wanted the code to find the position of the variable c, not the position of the *value* of c.

Thank you to all answerers.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `small_list.index(c)` is equivalent to calling `small_list.index(1)`.
The interpreter evaluates the value of `c` which is 1.

`index()` returns the **first occurrence** position of the specified value and that is at position 0.

See: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html